# When I used ng-include to load html dynamically, the controller of that html is not loaded

Tags: angularjs

I have following scenario

**assemblyHeader.js**

```
$scope.AssemblyHeaderDetails = function () {

            if {
                mixpanelEventTrack('Quote Details Clicked');
                var RFQDetailInstance = $modal.open({
                    templateUrl: 'Scripts/ng/View/QuoteDetailPopup.html',
                    windowClass: 'QuoteDetail',
                    controller: 'QuoteDetailPopupController',
                    resolve: {
                        AssemblyId: function () { return $scope.AssemblyInfo.assemblyid; },
                        parentScope: function () {
                            return $scope;
                        }
                    }
                });
                RFQDetailInstance.result.then(function (result) {
                });
            }
        }
```

Following is my **QuoteDetailPopup.html**

```
<link href="Content/PageCss/requestFormView.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div>
    <div ng-include src="TemplateUrl" >
        hello world!!!
    </div>
</div>
```

Following is my controller for html **QuoteDetailPopupController.js**

```
(function () {
    'use strict';

    var controllerId = 'QuoteDetailPopupController';

    angular.module('CalcQouteModule').controller(controllerId,
        ['$scope', 'DataConstants', '$filter', 'MessageConstant', '$modalInstance', 'parentScope', '$modal', 'urlConstant', '$timeout', QuoteDetailPopupController]);

    function QuoteDetailPopupController($scope, DataConstants, $filter, MessageConstant, $modalInstance, parentScope, $modal, urlConstant, $timeout) {

        $scope.TemplateUrl = 'Scripts/ng/View/requestFormView.html';
    }
}());
```

The problem is when modal popup opens it renders HTML page but didn't render the controller of requestFormView.html so the controls on HTML are not loaded properly.
For **requestFormView.html** the controller name is **requestFormController.js**
Following popup is opened when I clicked.

[image]

How can I load controller?

Comment: Have you added the dependencies for translate?

Comment: I don't know how to add dependencies for translate

Comment: Does the console show an error?

Comment: nope
even there isn't any error in network as well

Comment: Check more info about Angular translate https://github.com/angular-translate/angular-translate

Answer (score 0):

Add controller file in index.html and in app.js when you hit the url mention controller name over there. Hope this will help you.

Comment: requestFormController is already added in requestForm.html
When HTML is called it should load data from controller but its not happening

Comment: like QuoteDetailPopupController.js you have called your requestFormController?

Comment: nope. How to call requestFormController.js from QuoteDetailPopupController.js?

Comment: I don't know whether it's working or not but try this below $scope.TemplateUrl mention controller.